# ParamConvert in RoutetSubscriber::alterRoutes()

Tags: 8, routes

In Field UI RouteSubscriber we have this route:

```php
$route = new Route(
  "$path/fields/{field_config}/delete",
  array('_entity_form' => 'field_config.delete') + $defaults,
  array('_entity_access' => 'field_config.delete'),
  $options
);
```

{field_config} is converted to an entity because "_entity_form" has attached a paramconverter to it. How would I go about adding that to a _controller?

```php
$route = new Route(
  "$path/fields/{field_config}/delete/some-path",
  array('_controller' => '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\SomeClass::someFunction') + $defaults,
  array('_entity_access' => 'field_config.delete'),
  $options
);
```

Comment: Entities are converted automatically based on the variable name. The "_entity_form" has nothing to do with it. If yo uwant to provide entity as argument to your controller just name the controller argument properly. So if you have {node} argument then in your controller use method($node) (and ideally with interface as well). Symfony will take care of it automatically.

Comment: That's not the case though. The first is from the field_ui module in core. If you try the second example in a custom module by adding the route in RouterSubscriber you will actually get access denied. Because in the first example {field_config} becomes a full object, but in the second case {field_config} is "only" node.article.body for example.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing but have a look at comment.reply route or look for "parameters" in route files.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to call my controller using someFunction(FieldConfig $field_config)

Still very confusing. And you have to look what every of them actually want if you want to alter something like I do. The delete form in this case takes no actual arguments. The object is needed only for the access check. But the field_storage_config.edit form wants $field_config just as the string. If you add an answer instead of a comment I can confirm it.